# Display Zoom information

Tags: interface, uv-image-editor

In several graphics app such as **Photoshop** (or even other apps like **Word**), the view zoom is indicated at the bottom of the window:

[image]

<sub>Photoshop</sub>

[image]

<sub>Word for Mac</sub>

However, in **Blender**'s image viewer, I haven't been able to find such a thing.

The only thing I could find is the **View** menu, which doesn't tell you which setting you are on but lets you click on one of them:

[image]

<sub>If I select **"Zoom 1:1"** then go return to the **View** menu, **"Zoom 1:1"** will not have a checkmark next to it</sub>

***Is there a way to display the percentage of the zoom currently applied to the image editor?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blender doesn't offer a way to show the zoom level but we can use python to display it if we want.

The simplest way is to add a panel -

```
import bpy
import math

class Image_PT_zoom(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "Image_PT_zoom"
    bl_label = "Image Zoom"
    bl_space_type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        zoom = context.space_data.zoom[0]*100
        zoom_h = context.space_data.zoom[1]*100
        if math.isclose(zoom,zoom_h,rel_tol=0.001):
            self.layout.label(text="{:.1f}%".format(zoom))
        else:
            self.layout.label(text="Width:  {:.1f}%".format(zoom))
            self.layout.label(text="Height: {:.1f}%".format(zoom_h))

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Image_PT_zoom)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Image_PT_zoom)

register()
```

You can find this as an addon [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sambler/addonsByMe/master/image_zoom_display.py).

Comment: I tried pasting your code in the Python Console but got error messages, so I installed from file, but I cannot see where the zoom info is displayed? https://imgur.com/a/BNwJ7

Comment: In the properties sidebar `N` - the script above should have had a `register()` call at the end, add that. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtQ1R.jpg)