# Zoom value in Node Editor

Tags: python, node-editor

I'd like to know if it's possible to get the zoom value in the node_editor and, if it is, how ?

Comment: Probably related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89821/display-zoom-information but about UV editor. It could be similar in the Node editor as well.

Comment: it would have been nice, but there's no attribute 'zoom' for SpaceNodeEditor :(